# C# equivalent of php post

Tags: c#, php, rest

I have the following php request...

```
$response = $client->put($uri, ['headers' =>  ['X-Auth-Token'  => 'YOUR_TOKEN'],
                                  'json'    =>  ['soccerseasons' => '362' ]
```

I'm unsure of how to convert this request into a 'PUT' using the WebAPI library in C#. This is what I have tried so far.

```
HttpRequestMessage content = new HttpRequestMessage();
content.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "[YOUR-TOKEN]");
content.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("soccerseasons", "362")});

var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("X-Auth-Token", "[YOUR_TOKEN]"),
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("soccerseasons", "362")
});

var channelResult = client.PutAsync(new Uri("http://api.football-data.org/alpha/notifications"),formContent);
var res = channelResult.Result;
```

However, each call via the HttpClient object returns a 429 error: too many requests when calling PostAsync.

I'm sure this will be an easy question for somebody. What is the C# equivalent of the above PHP call?

Comment: For a start, it looks like you should be using `client.PutAsync`

Comment: So you keep editing this question with different code, it's impossible to help.

Comment: My apologies, firstly I was reacting to your point about PutAsync and then I attempted to tidy the code in the question up a little bit. This is the final version.